# How to write loop for webpage counter

Tags: java, html, loops

There's an element on a webpage thats a counter that looks like this:

```
<span id="counter_index_page_325846">00:00:51</span>
```

How do I write a loop for this element that does something every time the counter gets down to 00:00:01 and keeps doing it assuming it goes up to a minute every my action is performed.

this is what I have so far:

```
while (counter_index_page_325846.value < 00:00:01 ) {
    //perform action
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must do this way

```
 while (counter_index_page_325846.value > 00:00:01)
     counter_index_page_325846 = // assign new value
```

use greate than (>), otherwise while loop won't work